# mvn dependency:go-offline - how do you set params on the command line or at all

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to download everything except my own dependencies, which I haven't compiled yet.  I think what I need is `excludeGroupIds`, but how to I set it, or anything else in https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html on the command line?

I have tried this

```
mvn dependency:go-offline -DexcludeGroupIds=com.example
```

I have also tried to set them in `pom.xml` and `settings.xml`, and not been able to make them have any effect.

Comment: Any progress here?

Answer (score 5):

From checking the code of the maven-dependency-plugin, I'm pretty sure this is a bug, in the sense that the filters are not applied for `go-offline`. Here's the code that resolves dependencies in the [`go-offline` mojo implementation](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/resolvers/GoOfflineMojo.java#L98) (version 3.1.3-SNAPSHOT):

```
protected Set<Artifact> resolveDependencyArtifacts()
        throws DependencyResolverException
{
    final Collection<Dependency> dependencies = getProject().getDependencies();
    final Set<DependableCoordinate> dependableCoordinates = new HashSet<>();

    final ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest = newResolveArtifactProjectBuildingRequest();

    for ( Dependency dependency : dependencies )
    {
        dependableCoordinates.add( createDependendableCoordinateFromDependency( dependency ) );
    }

    return resolveDependableCoordinate( buildingRequest, dependableCoordinates, "dependencies" );
}
```

In contract, here is the code that resolves dependencies for the [`resolve` mojo](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/resolvers/ResolveDependenciesMojo.java#L102):

```
@Override
protected void doExecute()
    throws MojoExecutionException
{
    // get sets of dependencies
    results = this.getDependencySets( false, includeParents );

    ...
}
```

AbstractDependencyFilterMojo:

```
protected DependencyStatusSets getDependencySets( boolean stopOnFailure, boolean includeParents )
    throws MojoExecutionException
{
    // add filters in well known order, least specific to most specific
    FilterArtifacts filter = new FilterArtifacts();

    filter.addFilter( new ProjectTransitivityFilter( getProject().getDependencyArtifacts(),
                                                     this.excludeTransitive ) );

    filter.addFilter( new ScopeFilter( DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.includeScope ),
                                       DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.excludeScope ) ) );

    filter.addFilter( new TypeFilter( DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.includeTypes ),
                                      DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.excludeTypes ) ) );

    filter.addFilter( new ClassifierFilter( DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.includeClassifiers ),
                                            DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.excludeClassifiers ) ) );

    filter.addFilter( new GroupIdFilter( DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.includeGroupIds ),
                                         DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.excludeGroupIds ) ) );

    filter.addFilter( new ArtifactIdFilter( DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.includeArtifactIds ),
                                            DependencyUtil.cleanToBeTokenizedString( this.excludeArtifactIds ) ) );

    ...
```

It's pretty clear that the code of `go-offline` is not applying those filters when resolving dependencies. So I've inserted a ticket for the project to confirm: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-725

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.6.0 of `maven-dependency-plugin`, and perhaps earlier, the `go-offline` goal appears to respect the `excludeReactor` option.  It's working for my project, in any case.  This option defaults to true and appears to prevent the resolution of the current project's submodules, although [the description](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html#excludeReactor) (seemingly inaccurately) limits itself to "plugins" for some reason.  So, if you are using a newer version of the dependency plugin, you should need no extra steps to accomplish your goal by default; `excludeGroupIds` is not needed for that.

That said, [MDEP-689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-689) remains open, so I am not sure whether `excludeGroupIds` is itself now working or not.